# How to hide one div by hovering over another?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can I `hover` over one div, and cause another div to `display:none` then display again when not hovering?

I can `display:none` on an object I'm hovering but causing another div to `display:none` isn't working for me.

Thanks

Comment: Kindly share the relevant code, so that we can understand your problem better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, it's really quite simple:

```
$('.mydiv').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.myotherdiv').fadeOut();
    //you could also use $('.myotherdiv').css({'display':'none'});
});

$('.mydiv').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.myotherdiv').fadeIn();
    //you could also use $('.myotherdiv').css({'display':'block'});
});
```

The code above is assuming that your first element (the one that you hovered over) has a class `mydiv` and the div that has to disappear and reappear has a class `myotherdiv`.